# The code after my for loop doesn't execute

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a short program that creates an array of integers and removes non-primes:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] nums = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i){
        nums[i] = i + 1;
    }

    int j = 0;
    while(j < nums.length){
        System.out.print(nums[j]);
        System.out.print(" ");
        j++;
    }

    for (int n = 1; n < nums.length / 10; n++){
        for (int p = n; p < nums.length; p += nums[n]){
            if(p > n){
                nums[p] = 0;
                System.out.println("p"+nums[p]);
            }

        }           
    }


    //this code doesn't execute
    System.out.println("x");



  }
}
```

The statement which is supposed to simply print "x" doesn't execute, nor does any other statement I put after the for loop. The program does not enter an infinite loop, so what's going on? I feel like this is something obvious that I'm just missing.

Edit: it was an infinite loop, I just didn't realize it.

Comment: Looks like you are falling into infinite cycle. You never update your `for`-loop counter `n`

Comment: DEbugging the code you could check that the code is looping at infinite....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `p` loop, on the second iteration, `p > n` is true and you set `nums[p]` to `0`. From that point forward, `p` will never increase, because your incrementer is `p += nums[n]` and `nums[n]` is `0`, and so your loop never terminates.

---

This sort of problem is best solved by using a *debugger*. Using a debugger is a fundamental skill for a programmer. With a debugger, you can step through statements, inspect variables, and see exactly what your code is doing. It's not an advanced technique, it's essential from Day 1 so you can correctly diagnose issues with your code. If you don't currently know how to use a debugger, stop what you're doing and learn to use one, it will be incredibly valuable and time-saving to you. There's almost certainly one built into your IDE.

Comment: Oh yes, it was in an infinite loop. I'm new to Java and Eclipse and didn't realize it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Are you falling into a infinite loop? In the console press cmd+c or ctrl+c and see what that does. If the program stops it is a sign of a infinite loop.